# Streaming big video files with .net backend to react frontend

Tags: reactjs, .net, video, streaming

as I am creating an elearning web application with frontend in React and backend in .NET Core 7.0 I have stumbled upon a difficult topic for me. Assuming that i have **authorized** user wanting to see 1 hour long video that weights a lot (let's say 30gb) - in react i could probably use something like this:

```
const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState<string>();
axiosPrivate
        .get(`/SomeVideoService/Video?id=${id}`, { responseType: "blob" })
        .then((response) => {
          const videoBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
          setVideoUrl(videoBlobUrl);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching video:", error);
        });
return (
    <div>
      <video width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
```

With service being written like this:

```
    [HttpGet("Video")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "FirstRole, SecondRole, ThirdRole")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideo(string id)
    {
        var video = "video.mp4";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString(), "Videos", video);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;

        return File(memory, "video/mp4", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    }
```

However I am not sure what all of this does - i see the result and it is properly displayed on my screen (I do not have 1 hour long video, only 1 minute). In the network tab I see multiple data:image/ requests, near status code it is written 200 OK (from memory cache). The questions are below:

- When user wants to see video that is only for authorized users, should this video be sent by a backend video service as a memory stream, like I did it above? Static files are no option, since user must be authorized.
- How do frontend servers work exactly? One instance on "external" server and users can see it with their browsers? I mean frontend contains logic and views, and You need browser (that has Your IP and uses protocols to contact frontend server) to see that all and have the server generate transient version of its instance for user in browser (or project its views on users browser)? [this question is less important since answer can be some cool tutorial/explanation because i could not find any good for me]
- (1) Is the flow with provided code like this: user clicks "show video" -> browser sends it to the frontend server -> frontend server applies fetch for backend and gets video in full -> browser takes video blob file from frontend server in chunks; and now i see data:image/ requests
- (2) Or is the flow with provided code like this (i think this way is more correct): user clicks "show video" -> browser sends directly to backend service get method to fetch video -> video is downloaded in full to users' browser (big no no if file weights a lot) and then browser chunks it to smaller pieces and receives them from blob object
  (main difference is in the place where the video is stored after backend api call from user -> on user browser memory or on frontend server memory?)
- If second option is the answer - should I then use Ranged header for backend Get endpoint like this?

```
    [HttpGet("Video")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Common, Extended")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideo(string id)
    {
        var video = "video.mp4";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Videos", video);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        long fileLength = fileInfo.Length;
        var lastModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;
        var entityTag = new EntityTagHeaderValue($"\"{fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks}\"");

        var requestHeaders = Request.GetTypedHeaders();
        var responseHeaders = Response.GetTypedHeaders();
        responseHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600)
        };
        responseHeaders.LastModified = lastModified;
        responseHeaders.ETag = entityTag;

        if (requestHeaders.IfModifiedSince.HasValue && requestHeaders.IfModifiedSince.Value >= lastModified)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status304NotModified);
        }

        if (requestHeaders.IfNoneMatch != null && requestHeaders.IfNoneMatch.Contains(entityTag))
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status304NotModified);
        }

        var range = requestHeaders.Range;
        if (range == null || !RangeHelper.TryGetRangeItem(range, fileLength, out var rangeItem))
        {
            return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath), "video/mp4", enableRangeProcessing: false);
        }

        var start = rangeItem.From ?? 0;
        var end = rangeItem.To ?? (fileLength - 1);

        var contentLength = end - start + 1;
        var contentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(start, end, fileLength);

        Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status206PartialContent;
        responseHeaders.ContentRange = contentRange;

        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        fileStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return File(fileStream, "video/mp4", enableRangeProcessing: true, fileDownloadName: null, lastModified, entityTag, contentLength);
    }
```

Or if I wanted to do this method then i should have cut my 1 hour long video into smaller (10 seconds) files and serve them with this endpoint and somehow do it with this on frontend (the same react snippet would be for not cut version):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const VideoPlayer = ({ videoId }) => {
  const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const apiUrl = `SomeVideoService/Video${videoId}`;
    setVideoUrl(apiUrl);
  }, [videoId]);

  if (!videoId) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <video width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Apologize for the lengthy content and I hope someone would be patient enough to write it down for me. Thank You for reading everything and interacting with this post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code example with `MemoryStream` would be very bad for your use case since it loads the entire video into memory on the server before serving it. This would be a *huge* amount of resources for even a single request, never mind multiple.

There's no need to bring anything into memory at all. It can just stream from disk. It looks like the HTTP range example already does that.

Support for the HTTP Range is necessary. With HTTP Range, you don't worry about breaking the video file up into chunks since the web browser automatically requests what part of the file it wants, and the server will respond appropriately with only the bytes from the file that are within that range (using native filesystem APIs which I'm sure .NET provides). Without range support, the user would have to download most of the file to seek into it, which would be very bad UX.

Browsers will automatically send the necessary HTTP range headers as the user progresses or "seeks" through the video. But the expectation is your backend will support those headers.

However, I think you should pause for a second here before committing to this approach. Doing this is just a glorified (yet surprisingly efficient) download protocol. 30GB for 1 hour is pretty huge and many users won't have the bandwidth to view it. It breaches what many (possibly even most) people in the world have the capacity for on their home broadband. And don't even think about mobile!

At the very least, you need to encode the video using a sensible well- supported codec like H264 to make the size more reasonable.

However, this is also why protocols like [HLS](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/video/what-is-http-live-streaming/) exist. Coincidentally, HLS is built on the concept of "chunks" served over HTTP that you mentioned previously. But there are many libraries not just to encode the videos but also players etc. Many browsers and platforms already support it built-in, especially recently (would have been a godsend when I worked with video some years back!). Even those that don't can be made to with things like [HLS.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js).

HLS is more complex though and you should only go that road if you want the benefits. It requires encoding/chunking the videos at multiple bitrates, which also means the use of storage on the server side can be greater than a single compressed video. But therein lies the benefit; the quality will seamlessly vary depending on the user's available bandwidth. This may be necessary if you have quite heavy content that you want to work with a wide range of network connection quality.

It also allows you to control bandwidth on your side as well. If the bandwidth costs were getting too high (video streaming can be expensive) then you could simply only serve up the lower bitrates. There's no easy way to do that dynamically on a standard progressive download.

There's also [MPEG-DASH](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/video/what-is-mpeg-dash/) which works similarly on a fundamental level. However I believe the consensus is that HLS is better supported.

For authorization, yes, this is just something you handle in the back-end service. If they are not authorised, then you simply respond with a 401.

Your questions about "front-end servers" are a little confusing. Unless you have gone out of your way to have a front-end microservice you'd often just serve the front end from the same server as everything else unless you had specific architectural or scale reasons to break things up, especially in the early days of a project.

Maybe you meant front-end development servers like those provided by Webpack and Vite etc. But you don't run those in production.

By the way, I'm not sure why you are only seeing image requests in your dev tools. I just loaded a test video and I think they are just the little images for the play button/pause button etc built into the browser. You should see a request for the video but make sure you open dev tools before loading the page, click play, then observe. If it's a sufficiently large video and the server supports HTTP range, you'd also notice that at certain intervals, another request for the video gets made (for a different part of the range), as well as if you seek into an area that was not already downloaded.

Comment: Thank You very much for this broad answer, You have made my mind a lot more clear with it :) Thank You for pointing out that Vite is not production server - I am currently using it (i've started my journey with react a week ago, but have junior/mid exp on backend and some exp with pure js) so now I will remember to change it when deploying on prod. I started programming with a lot of C (ansi) so I am still not accustomed to things doing themselves without any help (talking about a way browsers and range request work) so maybe would You recommend something to learn how it works?

Comment: Also the data/image requests were sent from my browser directly to the created (with js) blob video file (with first approach using memory stream), that's partialy why it picks my brains how does the browser work haha

Comment: Cool. Yes with vite, in dev you want to configure the proxy https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy so that it just forwards requests that are not for the static assets to your "real" back end. For production you will do a `vite build` and sere the resulting files statically from your "real" server. Vite is good! But you just have to figure out the production workflow. https://www.zeng.dev/post/2023-http-range-and-play-mp4-in-browser/ seems to cover it.

Comment: In regartds to the data/image requests. Yeh, that's not really happening. Basically those are served from inside the actual browser itself and not your app -- to provide the default <video> tag overlay. They really exist within the browser. Just ignore them.

Comment: And when it says (from memory) it is a coincidence. Its not related to MemoryStream. It means it was served from the browsers internal memory. They are just little play, pause icons etc.

Comment: Oh yes I assumed it was from browser memory cache, gotta look on how browsers work haha, thank You for more information!